# UIPageViewController intermediate transitions programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with n (n>>2) pages. The first page is yellow and the second one is blue. When I drag from one page to another I get a nice animation for the intermediate states as shown in the following image:

[image]

I tried to make to page transition from one to another page programmatically. I got the `UIScrollView` as:

```
for view:UIView in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
  if view.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView.self) {
    self.pageScrollView = view as? UIScrollView
  }
}
```

The I set the scroll position like this:

```
self.pageScrollView!.contentOffset.x = screenWidth - deltaX
```

The result is the following:

[image]

The scroll position is updated but the next view is not loaded. This is why there is a white area on the right site. I know I can set the next page with `setViewControllers` but this will reveal the entire next page. What I want here is to reveal the next page programmatically only partial as I did with the dragging.

I know this can be done because the Tinder app is doing this already. When you make a pan gesture on the header the page view controller switches pages very smouth.

[image]

**How can I emulate the page intermediate transitions programmatically?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop halfway on something that is *paged*.  It is possible as long as a *drag* gesture is active, but as soon as you raise your finger and that gesture stop, the control will either show the next UIViewController or the one that was already being presented.

Using `setViewControllers` with `animated:true` will transition smoothly from the current UIViewController to the next as if you had *dragged* the view along with your finger:

```
.setViewControllers([allViewControllers[1]], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want something more custom, you may need to use a UIScrollView instead of a UIPageViewController, and set the content yourself.  Setting the `pagingEnabled` to `true` will make it behave like a UIPageViewController with a `Scroll` transition, but you could also keep the paging disabled and use a combination of `setContentOffset:(contentOffset, animated)` to make it scroll to your liking and the delegate `scrollViewWillEndDragging:(scrollView, withVelocity, targetContentOffset)` to make it "page".

---

I created a [code sample here](https://gist.github.com/simondec/57a1ad9ef02bb50def8b) to illustrate what I mean.  It is a simple UIScrollView that mimic a UIPageViewController, with basic view allocation/deallocation, and a way to scroll halfway programmatically.

Comment: "If you want something more custom, you may need to use a UIScrollView" Yes, that's what I told him, and he refused to accept that possibility.

Comment: How do I get the life cycle events for the different pages that I show in the UIScrollView?

Comment: @stephan1001 you have to make it yourself  (the UIPageViewController itself is essentially built *over* a UIScrollView).  One easy way would be to keep an array of all views (or viewControllers), then use the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate to compute which view(s) is visible at any given time.  `floorf(bounds.origin.x / bounds.size.width)` would give you the first visible view index, and `ceilf((bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width) / bounds.size.width)` would give you the last.  Remove all views which are not between those indexes from superview, add those that are in.

Comment: @Rufel could you please provide some sample code here?

Comment: @stephan1001 I updated my answer with a code sample!

Comment: @Rufel I did not see any methods which trigger life cycle events of UIViewControllers. I mean you have to use ``addChildViewController`` and ``didMoveToParentViewController`` somewhere?

Comment: @stephan1001 Yeah, I only did the basic to demonstrate the principle.  I have now updated the sample to include cycle events.

Comment: @Rufel please see my comment in the gist!

Comment: @stephan1001 I updated the gist, the two lines were inverted.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when you have a vertical UIScrollView inside one of the pages the outer horizontal scrolling should be blocked when the scrolling in the inner UIScrollView takes place. Could you fix that too? If so I will accept your answer.

Comment: @stephan1001 have you tried it?  When a scrollView is contained in another scrollView, the containing one is locked while your scroll the inner one.  It is already working the way you want ;).

Comment: @Rufel By the way what is the ``isDragging`` variable used for?

Comment: @confile  It is not used in the sample I provided, though it can prove handy if you want to do some specific handling in `scrollViewDidScroll` only when the user is dragging, since this callback is called even when you scroll the view programmatically (with `setContentOffset`).  You can omit it otherwise.

Comment: @Rufel Could you please help me with one last thing. I registered a ``UIPanGestureRecognizer`` on the header view then on a horizontal pan gesture I need to update the position of the scrollView. How do I do that?

Comment: @Rufel the problem is when I make the scrolling programmatically and when I stop between two page how would the end of the gesture makes the transition to the previous or the next page?

Comment: @confile if your title view has no controls, I'd make a custom view with `touchEnabled` to `NO`, and put it over the scrollView so the touch would register in it (no pan gesture required).  Otherwise its a little more complicated and you won't have the velocity/bounce:  use `setContentOffset` without animation when panning, and when the gesture ends, find the closest offset: `round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.bounds.size.width) * self.view.bounds.size.width`, and set it to the scrollView with `setContentOffset` (animated).

Answer (score 1):

Basically in swift all you need to write is:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([yourVC()], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is a good tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with setting a single `viewController` to make transition.

Like in `objective-c`

```
[self.pageControl setViewControllers:@[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:selectedPageIndex]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```